# Will a pull up resistor help the UART transmission accuracy on Arduino nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, uart, pull-up

On [A post from Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=282291.0) , someone mentioned that a pull up resistor over RX/TX pin could help the reliably of UART communication.

Is that really the case for nano and uno board?

Comment: *Nope*. Did you read the question and the answer on that post? This question was about connecting multiple TX to one RX with the UART (something that it was not designed to do). The UART actively drives the RX and TX pins both low and high and does not normally need pull ups (or pull downs for that matter). If you're planning to cross larger distances, you should look at RS232, RS422 or 485.

Comment: @StarCat But they said" Master will probably need 2.2K to 4.7K pullup resistor to bring the line high reliably/quickly."

Comment: *Please read the question and the answer for that post*. This was not about a simple TX->RX connection but a connection of multiple TX to one RX via a diode on every TX and a pull up on the RX. This is not the way that the UART is usually used and requires bus arbitration between multiple devices.

Comment: In my experience the BIGGEST gain in reliability came from using the hardware port instead of SoftwareSerial. MASSIVE gain...

Comment: @Wendall I'm having defects in hardware port, that's why I'm looking for better ways, I've already implemented twisted wire, and capacitors, so I'm wondering if pull up resistor will help for the fast response.

Comment: What type of defect? Fried at some time or not working the way you wish? Is it distance related? Baud rate? or ???

Comment: Is the interface RS232, 485, or ? You are not getting the data you expect. What is the layout of what you are doing?

Comment: Depending on the interface, capacitors will likely do bad things.

Comment: @Wendall Capacitors stabilize the power supply.

Comment: On power yes, but on comm lines is a bad thing... they will destroy frequency response.

Comment: Please show your circuit and elaborate on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not the case. Adding a pullup resistor on a normal UART will do nothing except maybe reduce your reliability.

You only want pullup resistors on something which is "open drain" (AKA "open collector") which has no way of raising the voltage of a signal line, only lowering it - such as I2C signals, or a shared open-drain, interrupt signal.